# Issue with #Jquery #DataTable column sorting and hiding columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

We are using [Jquery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). We have implemented server side column sorting. so when you sort a column, the data table sends the column index which was sorted.  So if you click on 5th column in the gird, it will send number 5. All this is working fine. But recently we added code to hide some of the columns.

```
 MyTable.fnSetColumnVis(1, true, false); // to hide the first column
 MyTable.fnSetColumnVis(2, true, false); // to hide the second column
```

Now after hiding lets say column 1 and 2, when I sort 3rd column (by 3rd column , I mean the 3rd column which is visible now, whos index is 5) at the server side I get 3 instead of getting 5 & because of this, we end up sorting on wrong column.

Please help. Is there any way to set some other property and when the column is sorted, we can send that property

Comment: datatables 1.10 has a super easy way to do this using column-selectors

Comment: @ZenCodr: Can you please give me more details. Or please share a link. Thanks !!

Comment: you aren't using datatables 1.10, since you are using "fnSetColumnVis", which isn't available in datatables 1.10. So this is of no use to you, but the docs for 1.10 are here http://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector

Comment: @ZenCodr: I am using DataTable 1.10.2. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Use this https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert to upgrade your usage. Added answer below.

Comment: Please post your column sorting code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the column name property in your sorting logic instead of the column index? See http://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side